# p style=display:inline trouble

Tags: css, text, inline, paragraph

I'm trying to create a list, with each `<li>` on one row. My problem lies at 'Food 4,' where I need to have a note describing the `<h4>`; I can't seem to clear the line break created by the `<p>`. I've tried `<p style="display:inline>` and every variation I could think of. What am I missing?

```
<div id="carte">
        <h3 class="list-title">Menu a la carte</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><h4>Food 1 $20</h4></li>
            <li><h4>Food 2 $30</h4></li>
            <li><h4>Food 3 $40</h4></li>
            <li><h4>Food 4 $50</h4><p>vegetarian</p></li>
            <li><h4>Food 5 $60</h4></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: `<p style="display:inline-block">` made no changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want both the `h4` and `p` to be `display:inline`. `h4` is by default, `display:block` so it'll take up the whole line. Same goes for `p`. We can set both of them to inline because the `li` is displayed as block as well. So everything inside the `li` is inline but each list item is still displayed as block.

```
h4, p {
    display: inline;
}​
```

[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/jg7Uq/)

Answer (score 3):

Do you want `h4` and `p` on the same line?

`h4` is by default `display`ed as `block` and as such has a `width` of `auto`... it means the whole line. So you should display **both** `h4` and `p` as `inline` and/or `inline-block` (or even `table-cell` if you want vertical aligning).

Edit: You shouldn't use headings if they aren't followed by text (`p` or lists for example). They should introduce sections of content. No content, no heading ;) except very rare cases. WCAG 2.0 Techniques [G141](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/G141.html), [H69](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H69.html), [G130](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/G130.html) and [H42](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H42.html) detail that.
It can appear quite uninituitive on the web, but you wouldn't leave a heading without paragraphs below in Word or Libre/OpenOffice for example.

Comment: Using both `<p style="display:inline-block">` and `<p style="display:inline">` made no visible changes to the page..

Comment: Do that to **both** `h4` and `p`.

Comment: Thanks @sachleen, I added the bold style to my answer too :)